# How to automatically adjust size of Qwidget with mainwindow?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, overlap

I am coding a to-do list App to display daily(in 24H format) schedules for a week, Here is my design:

1. in the buttom layer is a time frame using QtableWidget in a vboxlayout
2. overlap of the Qtablewidget,I use QLabels to display schedule.Qlabels not orgnized in any layout.

When the mainwindow resize, the buttom layer can adjust its size because of vboxlayout. What I want to know is how to resize the top layer when is buttom layer resized. or any other method to realize my idea?I overwrite the resizeEvent but failed.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui,QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget,QFrame,QMainWindow,QLabel,QTableWidget,QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter,QFont,QBrush,QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,QEvent

StyleSheet = '''
#central {
    border: 0px;
    background: gray;
}

QLabel {
        border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
        background: #CCFF99;
        font: 8pt Comic Sans MS;
        border-radius: 4px;
}

#mainFrame {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background: white;
}

QTableWidget {
  background-color: white;
  border: 0.5px solid #C0C0C0;
  color: #F0F0F0;
  gridline-color: #C0C0C0;

}


QHeaderView::section {
    background-color: #FFD800;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 8pt;
    border-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fffff8;
    border-right: 1px solid #fffff8;
}

QHeaderView::section:horizontal
{
    border-top: 1px solid #fffff8;
}

QHeaderView::section:vertical
{
    border-left: 1px solid #fffff8;
    font: 6pt Comic Sans MS;
}


QTableWidget::item::hover {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 0.5px solid #148CD2;
}

'''

class JobLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        QLabel.__init__(self,parent)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #99CCFF;")

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #CCFF99;")


class window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(window, self).__init__()

        self.left=100
        self.top=100
        self.width=1368
        self.height=900


        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Painting")
        self.resize(1368,900)
        self.setObjectName("mainWindow")
        self.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
        self.centralWidget=QWidget()
        self.centralWidget.resize(self.width,self.height)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("central")
        mainlayout=QVBoxLayout()



        ColumnCount=24
        RowCount=7
        JobBarHeight=20



        self.table = QTableWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.table.move(0,0)
        self.table.resize(self.centralWidget.width(),self.centralWidget.height())
        self.table.setColumnCount(ColumnCount)
        self.table.setRowCount(RowCount)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
        self.table.verticalHeader().setVisible(True)
        self.table.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.table.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        RowHeight=(self.table.size().height()-self.table.horizontalHeader().height())/RowCount
        ColumnWidth=(self.table.size().width() - self.table.verticalHeader().width())/ColumnCount


        hheaders = []
        for i in range(1,ColumnCount+1):
            if i<10:
                hheaders.append("0{}:00".format(i))
            else:
                hheaders.append("{}:00".format(i))


        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(hheaders)
        for i in range(ColumnCount):
            self.table.setColumnWidth(i, ColumnWidth)

        vheaders = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
        self.table.setVerticalHeaderLabels(vheaders)
        for i in range(RowCount):
            self.table.setRowHeight(i, RowHeight)




        mainlayout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(mainlayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)





        self.job_run_times=[["Sun 12:00","Sun 14:35"],["Fri 22:00","Sat 4:35"],["Tue 1:00","Tue 6:00"],["Wed 17:00","Thu 19:00"],["Wed 18:00","Wed 21:30"],
                       ["Mon 22:00","Mon 23:30"],["Sat 22:00","Mon 3:30"],["Sun 12:00","Sun 14:35"],["Fri 22:00","Sat 4:35"],["Mon 3:00","Mon 6:00"],
                       ["Tue 1:00","Tue 6:00"],["Wed 17:00","Wed 19:30"],["Mon 17:00","Thu 19:00"],["Wed 18:00","Wed 21:30"],["Mon 4:00","Mon 7:00"],
                       ["Mon 22:00","Mon 23:30"],["Sat 22:00","Mon 3:30"]]

        #job count
        n=0
        #label count
        k=0
        self.label_list=[]
        for job_run_time in self.job_run_times:
            start=job_run_time[0]
            end=job_run_time[1]

            weekday_start=start.split()[0]
            time_start=start.split()[1]


            weekday_end=end.split()[0]
            time_end=end.split()[1]



            for i in range(RowCount):
                if weekday_start==vheaders[i]:
                    Start_RowCount=i
                if weekday_end==vheaders[i]:
                    End_RowCount=i

            Start_ColCount=int(time_start.split(":")[0])+round(int(time_start.split(":")[1])/60,2)
            End_ColCount=int(time_end.split(":")[0])+round(int(time_end.split(":")[1])/60,2)

            #job time span multiple days
            DaySpan=End_RowCount-Start_RowCount

            if DaySpan==0:
                label_name="label_{}".format(k)
                label_pos=[]
                overlap_jobbar_count=1
                for j in range(len(self.label_list)):
                    if Start_RowCount==self.label_list[j][3]:
                        if (Start_ColCount>=self.label_list[j][5] and Start_ColCount<=self.label_list[j][6]) or (self.label_list[j][5]<=End_ColCount and End_ColCount<=self.label_list[j][6]):
                            overlap_jobbar_count=overlap_jobbar_count+1

                label_pos = n, k, label_name, Start_RowCount,overlap_jobbar_count,Start_ColCount, End_ColCount
                self.label_list.append(label_pos)
                k=k+1
                n = n + 1

            elif DaySpan>0:
                label_name = "label_{}".format(k)
                label_pos=[]
                overlap_jobbar_count=1
                for j in range(len(self.label_list)):
                    if Start_RowCount==self.label_list[j][3]:
                        if (Start_ColCount>=self.label_list[j][5] and Start_ColCount<=self.label_list[j][6]) :
                            overlap_jobbar_count=overlap_jobbar_count+1
                label_pos = n, k, label_name, Start_RowCount, overlap_jobbar_count, Start_ColCount, ColumnCount
                self.label_list.append(label_pos)
                k = k + 1


                for i in range(DaySpan-1):
                    label_name="label_{}".format(k)
                    label_pos = []
                    overlap_jobbar_count = 1
                    for j in range(len(self.label_list)):
                        if Start_RowCount+i+1 == self.label_list[j][3]:
                                overlap_jobbar_count = overlap_jobbar_count + 1
                    label_pos = n, k, label_name, Start_RowCount + i + 1, overlap_jobbar_count, 0, ColumnCount
                    self.label_list.append(label_pos)
                    k=k+1

                label_name="label_{}".format(k)
                label_pos=[]

                overlap_jobbar_count=1
                for j in range(len(self.label_list)):
                    if End_RowCount==self.label_list[j][3] and End_ColCount>=self.label_list[j][5]:
                        overlap_jobbar_count=overlap_jobbar_count+1
                label_pos = n, k, label_name, End_RowCount,overlap_jobbar_count, 0, End_ColCount
                self.label_list.append(label_pos)

                k=k+1
                n = n + 1
            else:
                label_name = "label_{}".format(k)
                label_pos=[]

                overlap_jobbar_count=1
                for j in range(len(self.label_list)):
                    if Start_RowCount==self.label_list[j][3]:
                        if Start_ColCount>=self.label_list[j][5] and Start_ColCount<=self.label_list[j][6]:
                            overlap_jobbar_count=overlap_jobbar_count+1
                label_pos = n, k, label_name, Start_RowCount, overlap_jobbar_count, Start_ColCount, ColumnCount
                self.label_list.append(label_pos)
                k = k + 1


                for i in range(6-Start_RowCount):
                    label_name="label_{}".format(k)
                    label_pos = []

                    overlap_jobbar_count = 1
                    for j in range(len(self.label_list)):
                        if Start_RowCount+i+1 == self.label_list[j][3]:
                                overlap_jobbar_count = overlap_jobbar_count + 1
                    label_pos = n, k, label_name, Start_RowCount + i + 1, overlap_jobbar_count, 0, ColumnCount
                    self.label_list.append(label_pos)
                    k=k+1

                for i in range(End_RowCount):
                    label_name="label_{}".format(k)
                    label_pos = []
                    overlap_jobbar_count = 1
                    for j in range(len(self.label_list)):
                        if Start_RowCount+i + 1 == self.label_list[j][3]:
                                overlap_jobbar_count = overlap_jobbar_count + 1
                    label_pos = n, k, label_name, Start_RowCount + i + 1, overlap_jobbar_count, 0, ColumnCount
                    self.label_list.append(label_pos)
                    k=k+1


                label_name="label_{}".format(k)
                label_pos=[]
                overlap_jobbar_count=1
                for j in range(len(self.label_list)):
                    if End_RowCount==self.label_list[j][3]:
                        if End_RowCount==self.label_list[j][3] and End_ColCount>=self.label_list[j][5]:
                            overlap_jobbar_count=overlap_jobbar_count+1
                label_pos = n, k, label_name, End_RowCount, overlap_jobbar_count, 0, End_ColCount
                self.label_list.append(label_pos)
                k=k+1
                n = n + 1

            for label in self.label_list:
                jobcount=label[0]
                label_count=label[1]
                label_name=label[2]
                Start_Row=label[3]
                overlap_jobbar_count=label[4]
                Start_ColCount=label[5]
                End_ColCount=label[6]

                JobBarLeft=self.table.verticalHeader().width()+Start_ColCount*ColumnWidth
                JobBarTop=self.table.horizontalHeader().height()+JobBarHeight*(overlap_jobbar_count-1)+Start_Row*RowHeight
                JobBarWidth=(End_ColCount-Start_ColCount)*ColumnWidth

                self.label_name=JobLabel(self.table)
                self.label_name.setGeometry(JobBarLeft, JobBarTop,JobBarWidth, JobBarHeight)
                self.label_name.setText(self.job_run_times[jobcount][0]+"-"+self.job_run_times[jobcount][1])

        self.show()


    def resizeEvent(self, event):

        self.centralWidget.resize(event.size())
        self.table.resize(self.centralWidget.size())
        event.accept()

        RowHeight=(self.table.size().height()-self.table.horizontalHeader().height())/7
        ColumnWidth=(self.table.size().width() - self.table.verticalHeader().width())/24
        JobBarHeight=20

        for i in range(7):
            self.table.setRowHeight(i,RowHeight)
        for i in range(24):
            self.table.setColumnWidth(i,ColumnWidth)


        for label in self.label_list:
            jobcount = label[0]
            label_count = label[1]
            label_name = label[2]
            Start_Row = label[3]
            overlap_jobbar_count = label[4]
            Start_ColCount = label[5]
            End_ColCount = label[6]

            self.label_name.repaint()
            self.label_name.parentWidget().repaint()


if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    win=window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're trying to set the geometry of `self.label_name`, but there is only one reference to the JobLabel, which is always the last one created in the `for` cycle where you create all JobLabel instances 
(near the end of `initUI`).

Each time you do this:

```
         self.label_name=JobLabel(self.table)
```

the JobLabel is correctly created, but you're losing the reference to the previous one (if any), so there will always be one single accessible `self.label_name`, despite they will still exist for the program (as it has taken their ownership, so they won't be garbage-collected).

What you should do instead is to keep the reference for all JobLabels, set their data accordingly and cycle through them when resizing.

```
class JobLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self,parent, label_data):
        QLabel.__init__(self,parent)
        self.label_data = label_data
    # ...

class window(QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def initUI(self):
        # ...
        self.label_list = []
        self.label_widgets = []
        # be careful, because you made an indentation error:
        for job_run_time in self.job_run_times:
            # ...
            # self.label_list.append(label_pos)
        # this for cycle should be aligned at the same line of the previous one,
        # while you have put it inside it
        for label in self.label_list:
            label_widget = JobLabel(self.table, label)
            # the following is unnecessary, as a resizeEvent will be sent before
            # the window is shown the first time anyway
            label_widget.setGeometry(JobBarLeft, JobBarTop,JobBarWidth, JobBarHeight)
            label_widget.setText(self.job_run_times[jobcount][0]+"-"+self.job_run_times[jobcount][1])
            self.label_widgets.append(label_widget)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        # ...
        for label_widget in self.label_widgets:
            label = label_widget.label_data

            Start_Row = label[3]
            overlap_jobbar_count = label[4]
            Start_ColCount = label[5]
            End_ColCount = label[6]

            JobBarLeft=self.table.verticalHeader().width()+Start_ColCount*ColumnWidth
            JobBarTop=self.table.horizontalHeader().height()+JobBarHeight*(overlap_jobbar_count-1)+Start_Row*RowHeight
            JobBarWidth=(End_ColCount-Start_ColCount)*ColumnWidth

            label_widget.setGeometry(JobBarLeft, JobBarTop,JobBarWidth, JobBarHeight)
```

That said, while your approach of tableview overlapping is actually a smart idea, there are several issues with your implementation.

- there's no need to continuously resize the header sections, just use `setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)` for both headers
- don't use the table width to compute the position (and width) of columns, as it would give unreliable values: you're using a division that returns a float value, while setting each header section size results in an integer size; if you use the Stretch mode as written above you can get the accurate section start from `self.table.horizontalHeader().sectionPosition(int(Start_ColCount))` and the size by adding all `self.table.horizontalHeader().sectionSize(column)` for the column indexes the label occupies; the same goes for the vertical size/position
- using fixed sized widgets will be a problem as soon as you have a row height < (todo height * concurrent todo count) as you'll get overlapping or wrongly aligned widgets; let's say you resize the table to a point where the cell height is 40 and you have 3 concurrent todos: the last object will be aligned to the next day, and if there's already another job there, it will be probably hidden

Considering what written above, I'd suggest you a better `resizeEvent` implementation:

```
    def initUI(self):
        # ...
        # remove both for cycles of self.table.setColumnWidth and
        # self.table.setRowHeight and replace them with this
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.table.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        # ...

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        # item views need some time to adjust their size (usually one "cycle" of
        # the event loop), resulting in incoherent positioning. If the "oldSize"
        # is invalid (a QSize with width or height < 0) we can assume that the
        # window has not been shown yet, so we ignore the event and create a new
        # one that will be "posted" afterwards, giving time to the table view to
        # adjust its internal geometry and eventually get the correct sizes.
        if not event.oldSize().isValid():
            QApplication.postEvent(self, QtGui.QResizeEvent(event.size(), QtCore.QSize(1, 1)))
            return
        super(QMainWindow, self).resizeEvent(event)

        hHeader = self.table.horizontalHeader()
        vHeader = self.table.verticalHeader()

        left = vHeader.width()
        top = hHeader.height()
        # adjust the job bar size if too small, otherwise keep the default 20px
        JobBarHeight = min(20, vHeader.sectionSize(1) / 6)

        for label_widget in self.label_widgets:
            label = label_widget.label_data

            Start_Row = label[3]
            overlap_jobbar_count = label[4]
            # I'm converting counts to integers as it's a requirement for range
            # functions, and these values are actually float according to your
            # implementation. You should make them as integers in the first place.
            Start_ColCount = int(label[5])
            End_ColCount = int(label[6])

            vPos = vHeader.sectionPosition(Start_Row)

            JobBarLeft = left + hHeader.sectionPosition(Start_ColCount)
            JobBarTop = top + JobBarHeight*(overlap_jobbar_count-1) + vPos
            JobBarWidth = sum(hHeader.sectionSize(s) for s in range(Start_ColCount, End_ColCount))
            label_widget.setGeometry(JobBarLeft, JobBarTop,JobBarWidth, JobBarHeight)
```

I'd also suggest you to use QDateTime for "job" timings, for two reasons:

- using strings to match the event day is not always a good idea; while you can hardcode them (as you actually did), it might be a problem if someday you decide to switch to another format (or even use localized day names for vertical headers, since you're using them to match the days);
- you could obviously have events that begin in a week and end in the next; if you're not very careful, you might end with events visible at the beginning of the current week, while they actually end in the next;

I assume you'll use some sort of string based serialization to save and restore event data, but that's not a problem as you can convert QDateTimes to string and back with [`QDateTime.toString`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toString-1) and [`QDateTime.fromString`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#fromString) using the [`QtCore.Qt.ISODate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#DateFormat-enum) parameter to ensure that the the correct time zone is applied.

Finally, while your approach is interesting, you'll need to be careful about it, because if you need to change the start/end data of each "event", it might change its resulting labels (possibly by removing some of the last ones if the event results in a duration that will not last to the following days).
I'd probably create a python class representing each single event that will keep (update and eventually clear/add) its joblabel widgets. In this case, you'll not use a main `self.label_widgets` for resizing, but will probably cycle through all events and then every joblabel widget the event contains.

Comment: thanks very much,your answer is really big help for me

Comment: @lijun you're very welcome. If this answer is really helping you in solving your problems, remember to upvote it and/or mark it as accepted! :-)

Comment: ,if i enbale the table scrollbar, How can the Qlabel scroll with scrollbar?

Comment: @lijun connect the scrollbar `valueChanged()` signal and compute the new geometries accordingly; since the labels will all translate by the same amount of pixels, you only need to compute the translation once and then set it for all geometries. Obviously, the more labels you'll have, the more slow the whole scrolling process will be, which is another downside of your implementation.